# force vlc to use libav, and pass libav specific options

Tags: vlc-media-player, ffmpeg

I have a stream, that I can successfully decode with ffmpeg, with this command line:

```
ffmpeg -f image2pipe -vcodec png -r 30 -i -
```

Now I want to to pipe it directly to vlc. I tried this one with unsuccessfully:

```
vlc - --avcodec-codec png --avformat-format image2pipe --avformat-options \{r=30\}
```

I suspect that the arguments are even ignored. How can i accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you specify the codec for VLC to use like so?

```
vlc --codec avcodec ...
```